# Responsive navigation opens when page loads and then hides. Should be hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, css

I am still new to javascript and have been using the responsive navigation:
 http://responsive-nav.com

The issue is that the responsive navigation temporarily shows up when you load the page. It should not be visible until you actually open the navigation.
The site that has this issue is: http://dev.sunnyvista.infront.com/

I know this style might have something to do with it:
`@media screen and (min-width : 940px) { .js .nav-collapse.closed {max-height:0;}}`

In the examples for responsive navigation, this is set to `max-height:none;`However, when I have it set to `max-height:none;` it displays the responsive navigation on any screen wider than 940px.

I've put the javascript now in the footer and before all of the other javascript loads for the page, but the navigation still temporarily shows when you  load the page. I've also tried putting the above media query in the head of the page, just to see if it needed to get the css style sooner. Neither have worked.

A second eye from someone more experienced with javascript would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What JavaScript are you using?

Comment: No problem from your side IMO, it looks like a bug in the plugin. Post a request on their github https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js .

Comment: Thanks, Olivier. I'm going to go ahead and post a request through github as well.

Jamie – I am using responsive-nav.js. https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:  https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js/issues/24

The issue posted above answers the question well.

Answer (score 0):

initially you have to set your nav to `display:none` and make it `display:block` on media query cut-off wher you want to display the nav.

For Eg:

**in normal desktop mode:** (better put it in top lines of your css file loading in `<head>` section)

```
nav {
    display:none;
}
```

**In small Device**

```
@media screen and (max-width : 760px) { 

nav {
    display:block;
}

}
```

Comment: thanks, Prasanth. I tried this but it seems to only sometimes work for  the first page load and then any page load after that the responsive navigation would temporarily display. I've tested it in Chrome v29 and Firefox v19